# How to set out of office status in Lync/Outlook without auto reply?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, lync

In our organization Lync statuses appear in Outlook next to the contact name.

When someone sets an out of office reply, a little asterisk appears at the corner of the status, showing he is out of office. Also Outlook show a notification in the compose window if the recipient is out of office.

I think these two are enough.

What I want to do is to have this asterisk and the message, but I don't want an automatic reply to any address (since the sender can see my message before sending me an e-mail).

Is it possible?

(This is the first time I want to use this out of office thing in Outlook)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, just clear any text in the message area.  You will be prompted with "An automatic reply message has not been entered and will prevent automatic replies from being sent. Automatic reply rules will work. Do you want to continue without an automatic reply message?".  Just click the "Yes" button and you are ready to go!